# In Amazon connect service provide concurrent calling feture means whn incoming call then all agents should Ring at same time

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-connect

I want concurrent call for Agents, means when there is incoming call then all agents should ring at a same time in a queue.

Expecting Concurrent call to all agents when there is incoming call please share any solution if exists

Comment: StackOverflow is a site for Programming Q&A. You will likely receive a better response at: https://repost.aws/

Answer (score 0):

Connect does not support simultaneous ringing for multiple agents.